# Read line containg only string and merge content to previous line

Tags: c#, html, .net, string-parsing

Input is:

```
<p>1:4 And David said unto him, How went the matter? I pray thee, tell me.</p>

<p>And he answered, That the people are fled from the battle, and many of the people also are fallen and dead; and Saul and Jonathan his son are dead also.</p>
```

In this first line contains numbers (1:4) and in second line only strings.

I want to find only strings in `<p>` tag and merge that content to previous `<p>` tag in html file.

Means:

```
1:4 And David said unto him, How went the matter? I pray thee, tell me. And he answered, That the people are fled from the battle, and many of the people also are fallen and dead; and Saul and Jonathan his son are dead also.
```

Can I do like this:

```
Regex.IsMatch(html, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$");
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to merge human paragraphs within a verse so that each HTML `paragraph` contains the whole verse, starting with the Biblical reference?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I got what you're trying to achieve:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string line in input.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    sb.Append(line.Trim());

    // notice different regex, i.e.:
    // new paragraph stars with `<p>x:y` and ends with `</p>`

    if (!Regex.IsMatch(line, @"^\<p\>[0-9]\:[0-9].+\</p\>$"))
    {
         sb.AppendLine(); // insert line break
    }
}
string result = sb.ToString();
```

Works form me, see sandbox: [one](http://ideone.com/k0k2HB), [two](http://ideone.com/ocOpoh).

Comment: Its not working for me.. plz help me to get only text <p> tag not number .. 

Means only 

<p>And he answered, That the people are fled from the battle, and many of the people also are fallen and dead; and Saul and Jonathan his son are dead also.</p>

Comment: @TinKerBell: `line = line.Remove("<p>").Remove("</p>")` will remove both tags but *from everywhere in the text*